# Restricting deeply-nested child records returned using LINQ

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

Given this object structure, how do I bring back a WorkItem, it's report(s), row(s) and student(s), but only the row whose Student's name is 'Bob' (I want to omit the rows containing 'Alice' and 'Claire').

> WorkItem
> ----Report1 (held in WorkItem.Reports collection)
> --------ReportRow1 (held in Report.ReportRows collection)
> ------------Student.Name = 'Alice'
>
> --------ReportRow2 (held in Report.ReportRows collection)
> ------------Student.Name = 'Bob'
>
> --------ReportRow3 (held in Report.ReportRows collection)
> ------------Student.Name = 'Claire'

(sorry about the formatting)

I thought something like this would work, but it still brings back all 3 rows

```
    WorkItem found = (from workItem in session.Query<WorkItem>()
                      from report in workItem.Reports
                      from row in report.ReportRows
                      where workItem.Id == 1 && row.Student.Name == "Bob"
                      select workItem)
                     .SingleOrDefault<WorkItem>();
```

**Update**
I also tried this, thinking it would only bring back the results when I actually try to use them (which it does) but looking at the logs, it still does a select for each student (I was hoping the 'where' clause in the final foreach loop would bring back **just** the one I was interested in.

```
    var query = from workItem in session.Query<WorkItem>()
                      where workItem.Id == 1 
                      select workItem;

    WorkItem found = query.SingleOrDefault<WorkItem>();

    foreach (var report in found.Reports)
    {
        foreach (var row in report.ReportRows.Where(x => x.Student.Name == "Bob"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--" + row.Student.Name);
        }
    }
```

This is my current best stab at it based on help from Ocelot20:

```
    var result = (from workItem in session.Query<WorkItem>()
                      .FetchMany(x => x.Reports) 
                      .ThenFetchMany(y => y.ReportRows.Where(z => z.Student.Name == "Bob"))
                  where workItem.Id == 1
                  select workItem);
```

The only thing that doesn't work is the *Where* clause for the student name. If I remove that, I get a result back (albeit with too many rows). If I can get the *where* clause right I think it will be bringing back what I want

Comment: Quick update: the best solution (by which I mean the only one I have got working) so far is Ocelot20's suggestion of using the 'Where' on 'someSelection' but I am pretty sure that's doing the filtering after loading ALL rows from the database, which is obviously inefficient. I haven't got a 'Fetch/Join' style solution to work yet (even using filters). I'll update if I get any further. V grateful to Ocelot20 because his answer has given me a lot to go on. Any other suggestions very welcome of course!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see here, you are only selecting a *`WorkItem`*. You are doing joins that limit the `WorkItems` that are returned, but you are still *only selecting* a `WorkItem` and not telling it to select specific `Reports`, `ReportRows`, etc. So essentially your query is saying: "Give me only `WorkItems` with an `Id` of 1 that can be joined with students named Bob". Note the lack of: "Then *select* that `WorkItem` with only the appropriate `ReportRows`.

My guess is that you're doing something like this:

```
WorkItem found = (from workItem in session.Query<WorkItem>()
                      from report in workItem.Reports
                      from row in report.ReportRows
                      where workItem.Id == 1 && row.Student.Name == "Bob"
                      select workItem).SingleOrDefault<WorkItem>();

// Doing something to select `ReportRows` without filtering them:
var someSelection = found.Reports.First().ReportRows;
```

Depending on how you have lazy loading set up, `ReportRows` will not even be queried until you call it on the `someSelection` line. At this point, it knows nothing about what you want to filter on. You have a couple of options here. First, you can just filter the items in the second query once you have already loaded the `WorkItem` like so:

```
// Filter on the second query:
var someSelection = found.Reports.First().ReportRows
                                         .Where(rr => rr.Student.Name == "Bob");
```

Or you could just change up your query to explicitly select the work item and related rows: `select new { workItem, reportRows = // select specific rows with a where clause here. }`.

Lastly, there's the nhibernate ability to specify what related entities should be preloaded into your selected entity. I know entity framework lets you add `Where` clauses on the related entities, but I haven't used nhibernate to know whether or not you can do something like this:

```
var customers = session.Query<Customer>()
                       .FetchMany(c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.Amount == 100);
```

If this works, this could be applied to your query to tell nhibernate to load the `WorkItem` with related rows where the `Student` name is "Bob".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Ocelot20. Using "var someSelection..." I get the correct rows returned (hurray!) but then at the end of all this I would like a single WorkItem instance populated with the rows held in 'someSelection'. If I create an anonymous type (new {workItem, reportRows = ...}) I guess I need to somehow convert the results back to a populated WorkItem. What's the recommended way of doing this? (I'm new to LINQ so thanks for your help)

Comment: The "proper" way to do what you want would be to use the `Fetch` methods if they do allow where clauses. You might want to research those first. If they do not, there's no real clear "LINQ-y" way to merge those together other than setting them manually.

Comment: Note that merging them back together and clearing out the old `ReportRows` and setting the filtered ones on that property may have implications in nhibernate that I'm unaware of. For example, they may consider any `ReportRows` added to the `WorkItem` to be new entities and try to persist them to the db. Hopefully someone with nhibernate experience can chime in.

Comment: OK thanks - I've been playing with Fetch methods actually. Trying to get one that doesn't throw an exception at the moment :) I think I may have run into a limitation of their LINQ provider although it's early days. Thanks a lot for helping me out. I'll update again when I've got something working.

Comment: After some searching, it seems that the "Fetch Where" syntax I suggested is not supported. Here is a question that looks to solve the exact problem you're facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432408/eager-loading-with-linq-query-with-restriction-on-details

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame. When I get a bit of time later I'll have a dig through the NH JIRA and see if there are any recent changes that might let me do this. Failing that, I guess QueryOver will do the trick.

Comment: If you found this information helpful in solving your problem please +1 and/or mark as accepted :)

Comment: Have +1'd it :). I'll wait until accepting if that's OK because I want to try and get it working as efficiently as possible (fetch/join etc) before I close the question.